# Find the least frequent occuring value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I made a table called `organizacija_akcije` and it has a column called `drustva_idDrustva`, now I need to find the value of `drustva_iddrustva` that is occurring the least number of times and I was supposed to do it without `LIMIT`, only with `having` or `having count`.

I have tried this code but it doesn't return me the lowest number of occurrence rather all occurrences and I'm stuck and don't know how to get the lowest one now.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
SELECT `Drustva_idDrustva`,
       COUNT(`Drustva_idDrustva`) AS `value_occurrence` 
  FROM `organizacija_akcije`
 group by Drustva_idDrustva
HAVING (value_occurrence) > 0;
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: sorry i am new on forum so i did not know, i will update and show data and expected result now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find `Drustva_idDrustva` with the lowest occurrence you may use `HAVING` and `ALL`

```
SELECT Drustva_idDrustva,
    COUNT(Drustva_idDrustva) AS value_occurrence
FROM organizacija_akcije
GROUP BY Drustva_idDrustva
HAVING COUNT(value_occurrence) <= ALL(
    SELECT COUNT(Drustva_idDrustva)
    FROM organizacija_akcije
    GROUP BY Drustva_idDrustva
)
```

Therefore, it returns those `Drustva_idDrustva` where their `count(value_occurrence)` is lower or equal to all `count(value_occurrence)` aggregates.

Comment: Very nice usage of `ALL`. I would use `COUNT(*)`, however, for clarity and remove those annoying backticks. @Matija: `ALL`means just that `<= all counts`, i.e. there exists no lesser count. Thus we are keeping the rows with the lowest count.